How to install @openzeppeling/contracts/security
When i try to write my code pops up an error in the following line:
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";

That says Imported file not found. Then I realized that in the node modules i have @openzeppelin/contracts but in this i dont have the security files. How can I install this part of openzeppelin??
Sorry i'm newbiee if someone wants to help, I will appreciate a lot. Thanks
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts-security
npm cache clean --force
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
